# Assigning values to output using source() within the server() function in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to organise my shiny app by putting most of my code into `source()` functions. My problem is, when I use `source()` to assign something to `output`, i get the following error message:

*Error in output$radar_all <<- renderPlot({ : object 'output' not found*

Here is my sourced file:

```
output$radar_all <<- renderPlot({
  
  colors_border=c(rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.9) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.9) )
  colors_in=c(rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.4), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.4) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.4) )
  
  radarchart(df = median_data %>% subset(cntry %nin% removed | cntry == "AT") %>% select(-cntry), 
             cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey20", axistype = 5, caxislabels = c(0,NA,2,NA,4,NA,6,NA,8,NA,NA), cglwd=1, seg = 10,
             pcol=colors_border , pfcol=colors_in , plwd=4 , plty=1)
  
  legend("topright", legend = rownames(median_data %>% subset(cntry %nin% c(removed,"Max","Min") | cntry == "AT")), bty = "o", fill=colors_in, cex = 0.9)
})

observeEvent(input$redraw_radar, {
  
  if (input$EU_check == T){
    removed <- removed %>% append("EU")
  }else if(input$EU_check == F){
    removed <- removed[removed != "EU"]
  }
  
  if (input$SU_check == T){
    removed <- removed %>% append("SU")
  }else if(input$EU_check == F){
    removed <- removed[removed != "SU"]
  }
  
  if (input$own_check == T){
    removed <- removed %>% append("PA")
  }else if(input$own_check == F){
    removed <- removed[removed != "PA"]
  }
  
  if (input$cntry_check == T){
    selected_cntry <- NA
  }else if(input$cntry_check == F){
    selected_cntry <- input$cntry_radar_all
  }
  
  for (i in stat_variables){
    median_data["PA",i] <- as.numeric(input[[i]])
  }
  
  output$radar_all <- renderPlot({
    
    colors_border=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.9) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.9) )
    colors_in=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.4), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.4) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.4) )
    
    radarchart(df = median_data %>% subset(cntry %nin% removed | cntry == selected_cntry) %>% select(-cntry), 
               cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey20", axistype = 5, caxislabels = c(0,NA,2,NA,4,NA,6,NA,8,NA,NA), cglwd=1, seg = 10,
               pcol=colors_border , pfcol=colors_in , plwd=4 , plty=1)
    
    legend("topright", legend = rownames(median_data %>% subset(cntry %nin% c(removed,"Max","Min") | cntry == selected_cntry)), bty = "o", fill=colors_in, cex = 0.9)
  })
})
```

I don't understand why I can't refer to `output` within a `source()` function. I've tried setting `local = TRUE`. Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Where are you sourcing the files to?

Comment: To one large app.R file. Problem is, I can't refer to the output variable outside of server().

Comment: What you can try is make a master server.R and ui.R files and source all the server side into server.R and ui side code into ui.R

Answer (score 1):

Let me cite [the language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment):

> Complex assignments in the enclosing environment (using <<-) are also
> permitted:
>
> `names(x)[3] <<- "Three"`
>
> is equivalent to
>
> `` `*tmp*` <<- get(x, envir=parent.env(), inherits=TRUE) ``
>
> `` names(`*tmp*`)[3] <- "Three" ``
>
> `` x <<- `*tmp*` ``
>
> `` rm(`*tmp*`) ``

Now, this works fine:

```
DF <- iris
foo <- function() DF[["test"]] <<- "test"
foo()
names(DF)
#[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"      "test"
```

However, if you try this in the global environment:

```
DF <- iris
DF[["test"]] <<- "test"
#Error in DF[["test"]] <<- "test" : object 'DF' not found
```

The reason is that `DF` is not in the enclosing environment of the global environment:

```
parent.env(.GlobalEnv)
#<environment: 0x000001d6f3d05688>
#attr(,"name")
#[1] "tools:rstudio"

ls(parent.env(.GlobalEnv))
#[1] "debugSource"              "knit_with_parameters"     "registerShinyDebugHook"   "RStudio.Version"         
#[5] "rstudioDiagnosticsReport" "RStudioGD"                "source.with.encoding"
```

(Strangely, in Rgui this returns the environment of the stats package.)

I suggest you try `output$radar_all <- ...`.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser! I had to assign radar_all to the global environment because I refer to it elsewhere in the app, and got an error "object output not found". I guess I'll just have to keep these code chunks in my original file then.

Comment: I believe `<-` will assign into the global environment if you source within the global environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.
Make a server.R file as follows

```
shinyServer=function(input,output,session){
source(s_filename1.R)
source(s_filename2.R)
}
```

`s_filenamex` are the files having only the server side codes